# Javascript - removing undefined fields from an object

Tags: javascript, object, field, undefined

Is there a clean way to remove undefined fields from an object?

i.e.

```
> var obj = { a: 1, b: undefined, c: 3 }
> removeUndefined(obj)
{ a: 1, c: 3 }
```

I came across two solutions:

```
_.each(query, function removeUndefined(value, key) {
  if (_.isUndefined(value)) {
    delete query[key];
  }
});
```

or:

```
_.omit(obj, _.filter(_.keys(obj), function(key) { return _.isUndefined(obj[key]) }))
```

Comment: What is your question? Your solutions already do what you want (destructively and nondestructively, respectively).

Comment: How much more cleaner do you want it to be, it is already clean!

Comment: I would use just `_.filter(obj, function(v) { return _.isUndefined(v)})`

Comment: I wonder which of these answers is the fastest?

Comment: Your `omit` example simplifies to `_.omit(obj, _.isUndefined)` (Underscore only)

Comment: With lodash: `_.omitBy(obj, _.isUndefined)`

Answer (score 341, accepted):

A one-liner using **ES6** arrow function and ternary operator:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => obj[key] === undefined ? delete obj[key] : {});
```

Or use *short-circuit* evaluation instead of ternary: (@Matt Langlois, thanks for the info!)

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => obj[key] === undefined && delete obj[key])
```

Same example using if statement:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
  if (obj[key] === undefined) {
    delete obj[key];
  }
});
```

If you want to remove the items from nested objects as well, you can use a **recursive** function:

```js
const removeEmpty = (obj) => {
  let newObj = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    if (obj[key] === Object(obj[key])) newObj[key] = removeEmpty(obj[key]);
    else if (obj[key] !== undefined) newObj[key] = obj[key];
  });
  return newObj;
};
```

Comment: You actually don't even need the ternary operator. Instead you can do `(obj[key]===undefined&& delete obj[key])`

The reason this works is because and uses short-circuit evaluation, so once the first check fails the second isn't even evaluated.

Comment: Even better! I updated the answer. Thanks for mentioning it :)

Comment: `!obj[key]` will not only remove `null`, `''` and `undefined`, but also remove `0` and `NaN`.

Comment: SO isn't a code-golfing site - clean, readable code is much more important than *as short as possible* code. The conditional operator is appropriate when you need to do something with the result of the expression, which is not the case here. If you just need to imitate `if/else`, I think it would be best to just use `if/else`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Fair point. I added an example using an `if` expression.

Comment: @Rotareti arrow function will break in IE 11

Comment: this function will modify the passed object, sometimes a nonmutating variant might be desired

Comment: is it worth checking the property exists first? 

`key in obj && obj[key] === undefined && delete obj[key]`

Comment: Poor coding practice, not using the returned ternary result in the top code. Or the binary shortcut returned Boolean. Same occurs with any C based language including C (excluding optimizer). Just stating my down-vote. *summarized

Comment: @TamusJRoyce I agree, I wouldn't use ternary and short-circuit like in the first 2 examples in general. But it's useful in situations in which your code needs to stay declarative. For example, I see this kind of code a lot in React's JSX templates, where it makes sense (IMHO).

Comment: Just a warning, the recursive function breaks objects with arrays in them. It needs an additional case to handle arrays.

Comment: @Erwin yeah I just had a bug due to this behavior. Have you fixed it? Can you or anyone else edit the answer?

Comment: I wouldn't agree with this answer being accepted. Although it sorts out the problem, the immutable way should be preferred. Since I put those usually in classes for the purpose of generating "update" queries, this is what I use: `Object.keys(this)
      .reduce((prev, curr) => this[curr] !== undefined ? { ...prev, [curr]: this[curr] } : prev, {})`

Comment: I dont understand why people keep posting obj[key] like that works, it is error to reference an object by a string. Error everytime

Answer (score 113):

I prefer to use something like Lodash:

```
import { pickBy, identity } from 'lodash'

const cleanedObject = pickBy(originalObject, identity)
```

Note that the identity function is just `x => x` and its result will be false for **all falsy values**. So this removes undefined, "", 0, null, ...

If you only want the `undefined` values removed you can do this:

```
const cleanedObject = pickBy(originalObject, v => v !== undefined)
```

It gives you a new object, which is usually preferable over mutating the original object like some of the other answers suggest.

Comment: The second argument to `pickBy` defaults to `identity`, so this can be simplified to `const cleanedObject = pickBy(originalObject)` if desired.

Comment: Or your code runs on the back-end and you don't worry about bundle size. Or your front-end bundler uses tree shaking and/or rewrites the Lodash imports (Babel plugin) so that you only import what you use.

So I don't think it's right to say that Lodash is way too bloated by definition. It depends.

Comment: It didn't remove nested null items

Comment: Null is not the same as undefined. I avoid using null as much as possible. Here are some details https://hamednourhani.gitbooks.io/typescript-book/content/docs/tips/null.html

This topic was not about null or recursion.

Answer (score 106):

## Use JSON Utilities

### Overview

Given an object like:

`var obj = { a: 1, b: undefined, c: 3 }`

To remove `undefined` props in an object we can use nested JSON methods stringify and parse like so:

`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`

### Live Example

```js
var obj = { a: 1, b: undefined, c: 3 }
var output = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));

console.log(output)
```

### Limitations and warnings

Depending on how Javascript is implemented.

- It is possible that `undefined` will be converted to `null` instead of just being removed.
- Nested `Object`, `Array` will be converted to strings
- `Date`, `time` values also converted to strings

### Tested

The above code was tested in Firefox, Chrome, and Node 14.18.1 and removed "b" from all obj arrays. Still I recommend exercising caution using this method unless you are in a stable environment (such as cloud functions or docker) I would not rely on this method client side.

Comment: this will replace the `undefined` with `null` and the entries are still there.

Comment: @GlennPlas add a plnkr  https://plnkr.co/edit/wP37G6BA5uJPSFz6xLTq?p=preview    check browser console for output

Comment: Indeed, strange I tested this in a project and it didn't work (I was using geojson objects and tried to clean out undefined features ), but this example indeed does what it says.

Comment: Actually, I recall the issue now, I had undefined keys, not values of valid keys.  probably was a bit too quick to comment here.  Tx.

Comment: Guys, this might look simple, but date objects will be converted to string. Beware

Comment: This is very expensive on large objects

Comment: Short but slow, and only works for simple values.

Comment: This is a hack more than anything. Formatting code to a string and parsing it back to code just to mutate something that can easily be done programatically? The unintentional side-effects (on Date for example) and computational inefficiency make that this answer should be downvoted IMO.

Comment: Keep in mind that this doesn't work with null values

Comment: JSON.stringify(value[, replacer[, space]]) - if you use your own replacer, it will work. There is no magic if you understand how the default replacer works. For older browsers, this method may actually be faster for large objects. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: JSON serialization is surprisingly slow. The time scales exponentially, not linearly, with the object size, also good luck with circular references.

Answer (score 37):

Because it doesn't seem to have been mentioned, here's my preferred method, sans side effects or external dependencies:

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: undefined
}

const newObject = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => {
  const _acc = acc;
  if (obj[key] !== undefined) _acc[key] = obj[key];
  return _acc;
}, {})

console.log(newObject)
// Object {a: 1}


// UPDATE: briefer version from @nicholas-hamilton with fewer assignments
const newObject2 = Object.keys(obj).reduce(
  (acc, key) =>
    obj[key] === undefined ? { ...acc } : { ...acc, [key]: obj[key] },
  {},
);
console.log(newObject2)
// Object {a: 1}
```

Comment: btw, I'm aliasing `_acc` to avoid the eslint error [no-param-reassign](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign)

Comment: I started using the `filter` + `forEach` and ended up transforming it to a `reduce` like this. 
+1

Comment: `Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => obj[key] === undefined ? {...acc} : {...acc, [key] : obj[key]} , {})`

Comment: @NicholasHamilton do you have to spread the first `acc`? Maybe just ...`? acc : {...acc, [key]: obj[key]}`... ?

Answer (score 19):

This solution also avoids `hasOwnProperty()` as [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties.

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
 if(typeof obj[key] === 'undefined'){
    delete obj[key];
  }
});
```

and you can add this as `null` or `''` for stricter cleaning.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a plain javascript (no library required) solution:

```
function removeUndefinedProps(obj) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && obj[prop] === undefined) {
            delete obj[prop];
        }
    }
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/djj5g5fu/

Answer (score 3):

Mhh.. I think @Damian asks for `remove undefined field (property) from an JS object`.
Then, I would simply do :

```js
for (const i in myObj) {
    if (typeof myObj[i] === 'undefined') {
        delete myObj[i]; 
    }
}
```

Short and efficient solution, in (vanilla) JS !
Example :

```js
const myObj = {
  a: 1,
  b: undefined,
  c: null, 
  d: 'hello world'
};

for (const i in myObj) {
  if (typeof myObj[i] === 'undefined') {
    delete myObj[i];
  }
}

console.log(myObj);
```

Answer (score 2):

This one is easy to remember, but might be slow. Use jQuery to copy non-null properties to an empty object. No deep copy unless you add `true` as first argument.

```
myObj = $.extend({}, myObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Javascript Solution

```
for(var i=0,keys = Object.keys(obj),len=keys.length;i<len;i++){ 
  if(typeof obj[keys[i]] === 'undefined'){
    delete obj[keys[i]];
  }
}
```

No additional `hasOwnProperty` check is required as `Object.keys` does not look up the prototype chain and returns only the properties of `obj`.

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/vicote/2/edit)

Comment: Except `Object.keys()` has it's own overhead in creating an entire array of the keys and it requires at least IE 9.