# Parsing JSON, return empty instead of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm hoping someone give provide some guidance on the below:

I am fetching JSON with something like this:

```
$.getJSON(jsonPath, function(returnedData){
...
});
```

The object returned will look something like this:

```
...
"skin": {
  "elapsedTextColor": "#ffffff",
  "autoHideControls": "false",
  "autoplay": "false",
  "muted": "false",
   ...
}
```

I make use of this data like this:

```
...
skin : {
  screenLogoImage : skinData['skinconfig'][0]['skin'].screenLogoImage,
  screenLogoUrl : skinData['skinconfig'][0]['skin'].screenLogoUrl,
  ...
},
```

When the value doesn't exist in the JSON, the set value is "undefined".

Is there a way to return an empty value if infact the value doesn't exist in the JSON?

For example, if in the JSON, screenLogoImage is not defined, how do I get

```
skinData['skinconfig'][0]['skin'].screenLogoImage
```

to return empty (so that the library that makes use of the configuration ignores it and uses the default value for that attribute)?

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "return empty"?

Comment: `skinData['skinconfig'][0]['skin'].screenLogoImage || [your 'empty' value]`

Comment: I mean ignore the missing key. So if a key is not defined in the JSON then when I try to set that key, then it just ignores it since there is no key (instead of returning undefined).

Comment: I'd go through skin and remove the undefined keys.  there are a couple of ways to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25421233/javascript-removing-undefined-fields-from-an-object

Comment: `undefined` is empty.

Comment: @Gavin thanks, your input got me on track

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `||` `OR` operator

```
skin : {
  screenLogoImage : skinData['skinconfig'][0]['skin'].screenLogoImage || settings.screenLogoImage,
  screenLogoUrl : skinData['skinconfig'][0]['skin'].screenLogoUrl || settings.screenLogoUrl,
  ...
}
```

or `for..in` loop

```
var data = {... screenLogoImage: undefined};
var settings = {screenLogoImage:"/path/to/resource/"} 
for (var key in data) {
 if (data[key] === undefined) data[key] = settings[key]
}

skin : {
  screenLogoImage : skinData['skinconfig'][0]['skin'].screenLogoImage,
  screenLogoUrl : skinData['skinconfig'][0]['skin'].screenLogoUrl,
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is probably the easiest solution to implement. A few months ago I didn't have to do it this way - if the key screenLogoUrl didn't exist in the JSON then it would be ignored when I tried to bring it in to an array.

I'm using the approach you outlined to defined a default value to prevent an empty value.

Comment: You could also use `Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) { ...  })`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the or operator if you want to give a fallback when defining things that might be undefined.

```
var screenLogoImage = skinData['skinconfig'][0]['skin'].screenLogoImage || "";
```

In this case, if it is undefined (or `false`), it will be empty string instead of undefined.