# How to remove key and value undefined in object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

how to remove key and value that are `undefined` from object?

for example I have

```
var x = {
 firstname: undefined,
 lastname: 'blabla'
}
```

how to get object without undefined? in the most efficient and quick way?

the result should be:

```
x = {
 lastname: 'blabla'
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - removing undefined fields from an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25421233/javascript-removing-undefined-fields-from-an-object) and [Remove blank attributes from an Object in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286141)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var x = {
 firstname: undefined,
 lastname: 'blabla'
}

for (let key in x) {
  if (x[key] === undefined) {
   delete x[key];
  }
}
```