# Return true, if all its elements are assigned to null. There will be another object with in that object

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular6

To remove empty rows from an object, require a generic solution.

The object has contain a list.

This is a sample object that i want to check

```
  {
    "test": {
      "id": null
    },
    "testName": null,
    "specimen": {
      "id": null
    },
    "specimenName": null,
    "collectionDate": null,
    "resultDate": null,
    "result": null,
    "finding": null,
    "resultValue": null
  }
```

I had tried this, but it will not work when there is a list inside.

```
purgeEmptyRows(obj: any) : boolean {
      let isEmpty = false;
      Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
          if (!obj[key]) {
              isEmpty = false;
          }else {
            return true;
          } 
      })
     return isEmpty;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you means. The parent node isEmpty = true if all the child node is null right ?

Comment: Object is  not empty, each element in that object is null. As I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38340374/2358409. This should be easily adaptable for `null` values.

Comment: Then your result will look like this one ? {
    "test": {},
    "specimen": {},
  }

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
this.findAndReplace(obj, null, []);    

findAndReplace(obj: any, value: any, replacevalue: any) {           
    for (var x in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
            if (typeof obj[x] == 'object') {
                this.findAndReplace(obj[x], value, replacevalue);
            }
            if (obj[x] == value) { 
                obj[x] = replacevalue;
                // break; // uncomment to stop after first replacement
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```

Comment: This recursive logic can use. To check whether this objects all elements are null, then return false, else true this is what my question about. No find and replace.

Comment: Ohh! my bad..Actually you have mentioned "Remove null elements from an Object" in question title that's why I got confused.