# how to cleanly handle undefined values with a yaml dump (js-yaml)

Tags: javascript, typescript, parsing, serialization, yaml

Using [JS-YAML](https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml) but this probably applies to other YAML i/o libraries.

I'm `dump` ing an object, and fields without values come out like this:

`fieldName: !<tag:yaml.org,2002:js/undefined> ''`

how can I suppress that to either `undefined` or just to skip it like `JSON.stringify` ? I guess what I want is to serialize something that would parse in again later, so I'm not sure what value. `undefined` seems to work for me with this typescript definition

[image: TSdef]

I tried some options from the `safeDump`

`const blob = yaml.dump(obj, { skipInvalid: true, lineWidth: 200 })`

https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml#safedump-object---options-

but without success. I guess I can strip out the undefined fields, but I'd have to do a `deep` clean of the whole object... also check for `false` vs `undefined` etc. etc.

I tried this but it didn't have any effect:
`const clean = { ...obj } // remove nulls?`

Sure there must be a nicer way to handle this with `js-yaml` ?
Do I have to define my own schema?

related:
https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml/issues/456
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38340374/1146785

```js
  async debugMessage(obj) {
    console.log('json', JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2))
    const blob = yaml.dump(obj)
    console.log('yaml', blob)
  }


// json 

{
  "msg": "router",
  "input": "sleep",
  "eventType": "action",
  "handled": {
    "handled": true,
    "doc": {
      "match": "^cont|.*",
      "goto": "prologue"
    },
    "klass": "room",
    "history": [
      "goto"
    ]
  }
}

// yaml 

msg: router
input: sleep
eventType: action
parsed: !<tag:yaml.org,2002:js/undefined> ''
handled:
  handled: true
  doc:
    match: ^cont|.*
    goto: prologue
  klass: room
  history:
    - goto
```

Comment: I use yaml-js in Node and I can successfully clear out the undefined fields with
 `content = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(content, null, 3));`